# What is the integral of $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+a^3}}$?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

> What is the integral of $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+a^3}}?$$

I came across this integration in a physics problem. I suspect role of complex numbers here.
'$a$' is a constant

Comment: The primitive function cannot be expressed in terms of 'normal functions'. You might be able to do it in some general cases, like for $a=0$ the integral is $-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^3}}$.

Comment: Complex analysis will hardly help here **unless** this was a Riemann integral: with limits and stuff...and even then it is not sure.

Comment: a is not equal to zero it has physical value

Comment: @3.14159 What kind of physics problem do you need it for? You might need to use approximations or a different method.

Comment: Do you have any bounds/conditions on $x$ and $a$? It would help if we don't have to consider all the possible cases...

Comment: @Bontod problem was solved using differential equations in the alternate solution. the other solution need evaluation of this peculiar integral. this

Comment: Would you mind adding the whole physical problem to the question? @VonNeumann added the exact result of the integral, but I think that won't help you out.

Comment: @Botond would it be okay to describe physics problem here?

Comment: @3.14159 You are free to add it as the context of your integral. Or you can just write it down here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other users said, this integral is unlikely to have an elementary form, however, it can be expressed in terms of the well known [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), which can be easily evaluated by most CAS or even Wolfram Alpha.

---

First, let's consider the case $|x|<|a|$, then we can substitute:

$$x=at, \qquad |t|<1$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+a^3}}=a^{-1/2}\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}=a^{-1/2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k} \int t^{3k} dt=$$

$$=a^{-1/2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k} \frac{t^{3k+1}}{3k+1}=a^{-1/2} \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(1/2-k \right) k!} \frac{t^{3k+1}}{3k+1}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}~t~\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(1/2-k \right) k!} \frac{t^{3k}}{k+1/3}$$

To find the hypergeometric form of the series above, we consider the ratio of the successive terms:

$$\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}=\frac{\left(-1/2-k \right)(k+1/3)}{ (k+4/3)} \frac{t^3}{k+1}=\frac{\left(k+1/2 \right)(k+1/3)}{ (k+4/3)} \frac{-t^3}{k+1}$$

$$c_0=\frac{3}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

Which, by definition makes the series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma \left(1/2-k \right) k!} \frac{t^{3k}}{k+1/3}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{\pi}} {_2F_1} \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}; \frac{4}{3}; -t^3 \right)$$

Which makes the integral:

> $$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+a^3}}=\frac{t}{\sqrt{a}} {_2F_1} \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}; \frac{4}{3}; -t^3 \right)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^3}} {_2F_1} \left( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}; \frac{4}{3}; -\frac{x^3}{a^3} \right)$$

This is a correct answer for $|x|<|a|$, as can be checked by numerical experiments.

Mathematica, or other advanced software, can directly evaluate and plot hypergeometric function, which makes this form more useful than the original integral.

---

For $|x|>|a|$ we can use the same method of binomial expansion to get the hypergeometric form.

$$x=at, \qquad |t|>1$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+a^3}}=a^{-1/2}\int\frac{t^{-3/2} dt}{\sqrt{1+1/t^3}}=a^{-1/2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k} \int t^{-3k-3/2} dt=$$

$$=-a^{-1/2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{k} \frac{t^{-3k-1/2}}{3k+1/2}$$

It's straightforward to continue in the same way and obtain another hypergeometric function.

Answer (score 1):

It's this:

$$\frac{2 \sqrt[6]{-1} \sqrt[3]{a^3} \sqrt{(-1)^{5/6} \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1} x}{\sqrt[3]{a^3}}-1\right)} \sqrt{\frac{(-1)^{2/3} x^2}{\left(a^3\right)^{2/3}}+\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1} x}{\sqrt[3]{a^3}}+1} F\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\frac{(-1)^{5/6} x}{\sqrt[3]{a^3}}-(-1)^{5/6}}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}\right)\right|\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)}{\sqrt[4]{3} \sqrt{a^3+x^3}}$$
where $F$ denotes the Elliptic Integral.

Comment: What is $F$, what is $\sin^{-1}$?

Comment: @klirk $\sin^{-1}$ is an ugly way to denote the arcsine function, whilst $F$ denotes the Elliptic Integral. This integral cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions, and Elliptic Functions are a special type of functions you will surely meet many times in the future!

Comment: The formatting could really use some work

Comment: @VonNeumann: Why don't you include this information in your answer?

Comment: @klirk Because they are supposed to be very elementary questions. If I write $\pi$ without specifying something, you won't surely think about a strange mystery.

Comment: @klirk The $f^{-1}$ is the 'standard' notation for the set $f^{-1}:=\{(y,x)|(x,y) \in f\}$.